# Initialize from html table

Tags: getorgchart

I have been trying to make an org chart using the code from this example http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Initialize-From-HTML-Table
I am making my table dynamically from xml data (planning to do this for many different xml files so thats why I haven't hardcoded the table). The result does not look right and I'm not sure whats going wrong. I suspect that maybe its trying to make the org chart before my table is made. I have no console errors and I get a plain blue screen with the search bar and arrows when I try to run everything.

Here is my html code:
https://pastebin.com/6b1d0gEC

```
<body onload="getXML()">
<div id = "conditions"></div>
<div style="float: right; width: 10%; height:100%; text-align:center; display: none;" ></div>
<table id="orgChartData" >
    <tr>
        <th>title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

Here is my JS code
https://pastebin.com/c7fFerqH

Here is the XML im using to generate the table
https://pastebin.com/0k3xQ5Th